# Firestore security rules based on map values

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store if a user is permitted to read a document in the document itself, based on the user's email address. Multiple users should have access to the same document.

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/arrays) Firestore does not allow querying array members. That'S why I'm storing the users email addresses in a String-Bool Map with the email address as a key.

For the following example I'm not using emails as map keys, because it already doesn't work with basic strings.

The database structure looks like that:

```
lists
  list_1
    id: String
    name: String
    owner: E-Mail
    type: String
    shared:
      test: true
```

All security rules are listed here:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /lists/{listId=**} {
        allow read: if resource.data.shared.test == true
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: It also doesn't work if I use `match /lists/{listId}` instead of `match /lists/{listId=**}`

How I understand it, this security rules should allow reading access to everyone if the value in the map `shared[test]` is true.

For completness sake: This is the query I'm using (Kotlin on Android):

```
collection.whereEqualTo("shared.test", true).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(activity, { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.i("FIRESTORE", "Query was successful")
            } else {
                Log.e("FIRESTORE", "Failed to query existing from Firestore. Error ${task.exception}")
            }
        })
```

I'm guessing that I cannot access map values from the security rules. So what would be an alternative solution to my problem?

In the [Firestore rules reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#map) it's written that maps can be accessed like that `resource.data.property == 'property'` so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: All the examples I've seen for resource.data don't have the ** wildcard syntax, so maybe resource.data only works if you use `match /lists/{listId}` instead of `match /lists/{listId=**}`? Something worth trying.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is also not working

Comment: Hmmm... I'll be honest; this looks like this should be working fine. Can you first double check that  you didn't accidentally store your data / edit your rules in the Realtime Database instead of Cloud Firestore? (It happens sometimes) Also, what happens if you don't make this a query and just try to fetch an individual document?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman The data is in Firestore. Not realtime DB. When reading the document directly with `db.document("lists/acaa0247-eccd-4ff0-b986-7f8b6187e45f").get()` it works.

Comment: this issue is still not fixed (March 2020) despite the claims of the most upvoted comment. So nested properties are not working. Since I can't comment with this account, this is posted as a separate answer. So please restrain from using nested properties in rules. They will work with local tests but not after Deployment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** This issue should be fixed now. If you're still seeing it (and are sure it's a bug with the rules evaluator), let me know in the comments.

I've chatted with some folks here about the problem you're encountering, and it appears to be an issue with the security rules itself. Essentially, the problem seems to be specific to evaluating nested fields in queries, like what you're doing.

So, basically, what you're doing should work fine, and you'll need to wait for an update from the Firestore team to make this query work. I'll try to remember to update this answer when that happens. Sorry 'bout that!

Comment: Is there any update on this or place to check ourselves? I am also blocked by this issue and with no good workaround (short of restructuring the data) we're left hanging

Comment: No update yet, but I know the team is actively working on it.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman is looks like from your edit this is working. Should it work with email addresses? There's a comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631421/firestore-database-rules-and-structure-for-sharing-documents-between-users that says it won't. I've created a new issue for this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265907/firestore-rules-and-query-for-document-map-with-email-keys-to-share-data-with-us

Comment: Hello, having a similiar problem here which is very confusing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929366/cloud-firestore-reactjs-error-missing-or-insufficient-permissions Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have **(optional) nested properties** you should make sure the property exists before continuing to check its' value eg.

```
allow read: if role in request.auth.token && request.auth.token[role] == true
```

in your case:

```
allow read: if test in resource.data.shared && resource.data.shared.test == true
```

, I was struggling a long time with roles until I realized that on non-admin users the admin field is undefined and firestore rules just crashes and doesn't continue checking other possible matches.

For a user without token.admin, this will always **crash** no matter if you have other matches that are true eg:

```
function userHasRole(role) {
  return isSignedIn() && request.auth.token[role] == true
}
```