# Firebase firestore rules, read only when document contain specific value

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I was learning through official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/secure-data#evaluating_documents_currently_in_the_database) for security rules, but i cant make it work.

in my collections `users` under document `user` have some map values, one of them is `role: "guest"`. role values can be `"guest" or "superAdmin"`

i want access to `/users` only when `role == "superAdmin"`

here is what i tried

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.role == "superAdmin";
    }
  }
}
```

and got error when i log in as `superAdmin`

> ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.

i believe i followed docs correctly. and found a similar question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674372/firestore-security-rules-based-on-map-values) where says some bug specific to evaluating nested fields in queries. But i have no nested queries. am i doing anything wrong here?

here is my firestore look

[image]

Please help.

Comment: looks like a bug in firestore, its still in beta. found an alternative solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629170/firestore-security-rule-get-not-work). waiting for a correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `get()`, since you're fetching the document at the location you're reading from, simply address it using `resource` (which is the prefetched document at that location):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read: if resource.data.role == "superAdmin";
    }
  }
}
```

Only use `get()` if you're going to a different collection to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the part that breaks it is `allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId))`. Here you are comparing the owner of the document, not the one requesting it. Try replacing `userID` with `request.auth.uid`.

Comment: you said it right. i tried it and waited 10 mins, but unfortunately same error. `if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "superAdmin"`  is it correct?