# Firestore rules and query for document map with email keys to share data with users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Use Case Summary**

1. User A creates a story
2. User A shares story with unknown (to the app) User B via email (sent via cloud function)
3. User B receives an email about the story
4. User B visits app and creates a new account
5. User B sees/reads story create by User A

**Note:** stories can only be seen by whom they been shared with or created by

I'm building a role based access system. I've been looking at the [role based access firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access) and I'm missing one piece.

Consider a story that can only be read by a user for which that story has been shared. Most examples including the firestore example use the `UID` has the key to identify shared users. However, that user may not currently be a user of the firebase app additionally how does a user assign that UID.

**Story Data**

```
{
  title: "A Great Story",
  roles: {
    aliceUID: {
      hasRole: true,
      type: "owner",
    },
    bobUID: {
      hasRole: true,
      type: "reader",
    }
  }
}
```

**Story Query**

```
firebase.firestore().collection('stories').where(`roles.${user.uid}.hasRole`, '==', true)
```

The second part could potentially be solved by maintaining a separate user collection then you could find the user from their email address, but this doesn't address users that have never logged in.

The user who intends to share a story could add the user with an email address. Then using firebase functions we could send an email to notify the user of the shared story and the user could login to the app and read that story.

If we proceed with this method then you would not have a UID but only an email address as the key.

**Story Data**

```
{
  title: "A Great Story",
  roles: {
    alice@yahoo.com: {
      hasRole: true,
      type: "owner",
    },
    bob@gmail.com: {
      hasRole: true,
      type: "reader",
    }
  }
}
```

**Story Query**

```
firebase.firestore().collection('stories').where(`roles.${user.email}.hasRole`, '==', true)
```

**Updated Firestore Rule** - from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access)

```
function getRole(rsc) {
  // Read from the "roles" map in the story document.
  return rsc.data.roles[request.auth.uid] || rsc.data.roles[request.auth.token.email];
}
```

I can not get the email query to work. This [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631421/firestore-database-rules-and-structure-for-sharing-documents-between-users) mentions that

> Unfortunately dots are not allowed as a map key. So email addresses won't work.

I don't see why this would be a conflict on the rules side. It does make for a likely invalid where clause

e.g.

```
.where(`roles.${user.email}.hasRole`, '==', true) -> .where(`roles.bob@gmail.com.hasRole`, '==', true)
```

That looks like invalid JS and unfortunately `[` and `]` are invalid characters so we can't do

```
.where(`roles[${user.email}]hasRole`, '==', true)
```

The final thing I've seen is using for this [Firebase talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/vtX8lfxxShk) is to escape the email address using something like

```
function encodeAsFirebaseKey(string) {
  return string.replace(/\%/g, '%25')
    .replace(/\./g, '%2E')
    .replace(/\#/g, '%23')
    .replace(/\$/g, '%24')
    .replace(/\//g, '%2F')
    .replace(/\[/g, '%5B')
    .replace(/\]/g, '%5D');
};
```

This appears to fix the query `where` clause and it's a valid data structure, but it's not a [valid Firestore rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#developer_defined) meaning it has no true security enforcement.

Any ideas on how to implement this? Please include valid data structure, firestore rules, and query. I've shown and seen many examples that get two out of the three which are all non-working solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic issue was that I did not know how to properly formulate a valid query. It turns out that you don't need to create a query in one line.

You can use [FieldPath](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath) to construct your query parameter.

```
var path = new firebase.firestore.FieldPath('roles', email ,'hasRole');
firebase.firestore().collection('stories').where(path, '==', true)
```

This solves for the original missing piece.

Comment: Funny, I am working on a super similar case and your answer helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for [Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user
>   accounts. This provides the ability to implement various access
>   control strategies, including role-based access control, in Firebase
>   apps. These custom attributes can give users different levels of
>   access (roles), which are enforced in an application's security rules.
>
> User roles can be defined for the following common cases:
>
> - Giving a user administrative privileges to access data and resources.
> - Defining different groups that a user belongs to.
> - Providing multi-level access:
> - Differentiating paid/unpaid subscribers.
> - Differentiating moderators from regular users.
> - Teacher/student application, etc.

You'll need to stand up a node server (skill level low). A script like below works to generate the claims.

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./blah-blah-blah.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com"
});

admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims("9mB3asdfrw34ersdgtCk1", {admin: true}).then(() => {
    console.log("Custom Claim Added to UID. You can stop this app now.");
});
```

Then on your client side, do something like:

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {

```
    //is email address up to date? //do we really want to modify it or mess w it?
    switch (user.providerData[0].providerId) {
        case 'facebook':
        case 'github':
        case 'google':
        case 'twitter':
            break;
        case 'password':
            // if (!verifiedUser) {
            // }
            break;
    }

    //if admin
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {
        // Parse the ID token.
        const payload = JSON.parse(window.atob(idToken.split('.')[1]));
        // Confirm the user is an Admin or whatever
        if (!!payload['admin']) {
            switch (thisPage) {
                case "/admin":
                    showAdminStuff();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(isAdminPage()){
                document.location.href="/";
            }
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
else {
    //USER IS NOT SIGNED IN

}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the info I think that's must have been the only docs section I hadn't read thoroughly. The docs all reference the Realtime Database and the mapping to Firestore rules is not clear to me. Creating a custom claim seems straight forward, but I don't see how to share a single story with a user that's never used this app. We could add a custom claim for every story but that push up against the 1000 bytes at some point.

Comment: data is either readable or not. If you want to limit who has read access, custom claims could be used to create categories of access, e.g. 8th graders, 9th graders, college students.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered, you want to make a story private but shareable with anyone. Your biggest concern is for users who do not have the app but have the share link.

And therefore your biggest problem is that the way firebase works means that you cant limit access to your data without using some sort of login.

If you are ok with requiring new users to login, then your answer should just be Dynamic Links. These links are persistent all the way though installation and login which means that anyone can be given a dynamic link that has story access data attached. You would merely need to add a listener to your app's `mainActivity` or `AppDelegate` equivalent to record the dynamic link data and run a specif task after login.

If you wish to stay away from the login completely, then you set up the dynamic link to bypass the login process and direct the new-install-user directly to the story. This second option however, requires a bit more work and is less secure because you will probably be forced to duplicate the story data for open access to anyone with the proper link to the story.

Comment: I haven't worked with it but you might be able to achieve the 'no-login' effect that I mentioned with firebase's anonymous login feature but I have never use it so it's just a suggestion to look into if that's what you need and you want to keep your database secure,

Comment: Dynamic Links look very promising and that was my initial though. However, I'm creating a web app so I believe that will result in just a regular link. The docs don't mention receiving dynamic links for web. Maybe because it's just a url? With that in mind I would need to update the story roles map with some identifier, I'm already using the email and then once the user logs in I would need to update that email key with their UID. I think that works but cloud functions don't execute on a guaranteed time so the user might not initially see the story.